# Displaying Array in One Message Box in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I'm trying to display this separated string in one message box rather than them all popping up separately one after another. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim variables As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim arrResult() As String

    variables = "3.09, 1.26, 3.4, 2.098"
    arrResult = variables.Split(",")
    For count = 0 To arrResult.Length - 1
        MsgBox(arrResult(count))
    Next
```

Comment: is this to hard for you?  `MsgBox(variables.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Replace(",", vbCrLf))`

Comment: @Mary Absolutely NOT. If this assume that meaning in your mind that remains only a your problem not mine. BTW I hope your comment was not meant to be superior with this kind of moral advises. Thank you for the tip about my english. Have fun

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Very glad to hear you meant it kindly. Sarcasm is very common in the North East USA. I just thought you would like to know about to/too. Your English is probably better than mine and I am a native.

Comment: @Mary Sarcasm sometime it’s not completely understood by others,( not in this case ;) I  think). So, thanks again for your kindly words and let me say that, yes I’m here to practice my English as I’m a beginner in that. Conversations like yours make me motivated to continue ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's two way you could go about it.

**FIRST**

Before your loop, you could declare a variable say `Dim allElements As String = ""` then
replace your `MsgBox(arrResult(count))` inside your loop to `allElements &= arrResult(count) & vbNewLine`, finally after your loop `MsgBox(allElements)`

**SECOND**

Just remove your loop, then use `MsgBox(variables)`